# React reload call api function doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

Below a simple react component loads a list of twits.
I use a "request-promise" package to get the data.
First call works quite well (with hook effect).
The issue is that the reload function doesn't work.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { tw } from './twitProxy'

//tw contains a simple promise request with twitter's api call.

function Twitter(){
    let [twe, setTw] = useState()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        tw.then((data)=>{
            setTw(JSON.parse(data))
        })
    }, [])

    const reloadTwit = () => {
        tw.then((data)=>{
            console.log("reload twit without call api ? ")
            setTw(JSON.parse(data))
        })
    }


    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                 {
                     (twe !== undefined) ? 
                        twe.map((value, index) => {
                            return <li key={index}>{value.text}</li>
                        })
                        : console.log("loading")

                 }
                 <button onClick={reloadTwit}>Reload Twitter</button>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Twitter
```

Comment: why is reloadTwit async?

Comment: i made some tests it's useless here.(removed)

Comment: Why are you using a request promise package? If you are on the front-end you should use fetch.

Comment: thank for the advise i will switch.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Twitter(){
    let [twe, setTw] = useState()
    let [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    const reloadTwit = () => {
        setCount(count + 1)
    }

  React.useEffect(() => {
        tw.then((data)=>{
            console.log("reload twit without call api ? ")
            setTw(JSON.parse(data))
        })
    }, [count])


    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                 {
                     (twe !== undefined) ? 
                        twe.map((value, index) => {
                            return <li key={index}>{value.text}</li>
                        })
                        : console.log("loading")

                 }
                 <button onClick={reloadTwit}>Reload Twitter</button>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Twitter
```

Comment: Thank you,  i will try your solution but i think that i already done a thing like that.